# How find best circle from cv2.HoughCircles

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using

```
cv2.HoughCircles
```

function of python.

I want to find circles in an image like this:

[image]

In this image there is a big circle and many little circles. I want only the biggest.

The image has dimension 280x300 pixels, but if I set as function's parameters minRadius=90 and maxRadius=150

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(edges, cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 30,
>               param1=20,
>               param2=10,
>               minRadius=80,
>               maxRadius=150)

print (circles)
```

I find an output like this:

```
  [[[ 149.5         125.5         141.63510132]
  [ 141.5         155.5         112.5544281 ]
  [ 173.5         144.5         103.35617828]
  [ 115.5         134.5          98.32852936]
  [ 173.5         105.5          87.82083893]
  [ 174.5         176.5          85.20856476]
  [ 130.5          99.5          83.69289398]
  [ 105.5         165.5          81.62413788]
  [ 141.5         187.5          80.62567902]
  [  75.5         134.5         104.03124237]]]
```

So, I think that all these circles are possible, but probably one of these results is best than the others. How can I find it?

Comment: From the doc: _"Circles, corresponding to the larger accumulator values, will be returned first."_. So the best one (in the Hough "sense") is the first one

Comment: if you want to post process your detected circles you could use chamfer matching or similar to find max or average distance from the circle to the edges.

Answer (score 4):

Fourth function's parameter is the minimum distance between the centers of the detected circles. To find only one circles you should only set this parameter bigger.